# My .sh script points to home and not in current dir

Tags: unix

I don't know what is happening to my script. 
I'm trying to run my .sh script (#!/bin/bash) in a folder in which I have permissions but that is not in my home (/home/myname/) on a cluster (PBS). If I specify cd /...../ the data are read in the current working dir otherwise if I write cd ${PWD}  or export PATH=$PATH:$(pwd)
the current path is ignored and the .sh points to the home dir where of course data are not found. I'm really getting crazy about this. 
Can anyone help me understand what is happening?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you tried setting `pwd` to a variable within the scrip and using that instead of `pwd` itself? Also, are you running the script from the folder that you want to read data from?

Comment: Oh I don't understand your suggestion

Comment: Instead of using the `$PWD` in the script, try `CWD=${pwd}` and user `$CWD` as `$PWD`.

Comment: maybe you need `cd /my/special/project/data` (or similar) at the top of your script? Otherwise, your Q is unclear (IHMO), please read [mcve] and in any case not really about programming. Consider moving it to http://superuser.com . Good luck.

Comment: Your question is very unclear (to me at least), because you don't give names to things. You have a script, `/home/myname/foo.sh`, you want to run it in `/cluster/place/`, and your initial working directory is `/somewhere/else/`. You tried `cd /cluster/place; ~/foo.sh` and *what* happened?